# IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TaskList(models.Model):
    manage = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task + " - " + str(self.done)
```

I keep getting this error: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__todolist_app_tasklist.manage_id after I "python manage.py migrate".

Any suggestions?

Comment: you try to add  a non nullable  foreign key to a table that contains  data

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `ForeignKey` to `null=True` to allow `None` values, as this is the default you defined.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TaskList(models.Model):
    manage = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # ...
```

As you are setting `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, all `TaskList` of a user will be deleted, if you delete the related `User` object.
If this is the desired behaviour, `null=True, default=None` should not be necessary and used.

If you like to keep the `TaskList` even if the `User` ist deleted, use `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`, as yopu already having `TaskList` objects with `None` values for the `manage` field.

Comment: I truly appreciate this! I am still having issues, however, is there somewhere else within my project I should look?